# To have some sort of thing for something... what does it mean?

Tags: word-in-context

What's the meaning of the phrase "I have some sort of a thing for owls and trees lately". I tried to translate it for Portuguese but all I get is literal translations and it doesn't make any sense. Does it means that he or she is has a crush on owls and trees or something like that.

If that is correct may this kind of expression be used when talking about human beings as well, like in the phrase: "I'm not sure but I think she has some sort of a thing for me" or "He is a bit older now, but all the girls still seem to have some sort of a thing for him"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I have some sort of a thing for x", or (as I've heard more frequently) "I've got a thing about x", means that x has some kind of emotional importance or interest for me.

It can be negative:

> "I have a thing about gophers. I hate them because they eat my tulips."

But usually it is a positive interest, and often romantic, especially if you use the word "**for**":

> "He always seemed to be surrounded by adoring females. Apparently lots
>   of women have a thing for musicians, especially drummers."
>
> "We always had cats and dogs around. Our whole family had a thing
>   about stray animals."
>
> "Ever since I was a little kid I've had this thing about Christmas."
>
> "He's been coming over here a lot lately. I think he has a thing for
>   my mom."

Answer (score 2):

To "have a thing" for, or about, something or someone can mean, informally, a passion, liking, interest or preference. You could have a thing for blondes, chocolate, Fiat cars, Mozart, or swimming.

> have a thing for
>
> informal Have a strong liking for.
>
> ‘I think he has a bit of a thing for you’
>   ‘She's the young hotshot of the woman's tennis circuit and she seems to have a thing for Peter.’
>   ‘She and I have a thing for the movies and never miss the opening
>   night of anything.’
>   ‘She apparently had a thing for smart guys.’
>   ‘People will think I really do have a thing for meteorites.’

[Thing (Oxford Dictionaries)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/thing)